# keyboard backlit - Ubuntu 12.10 - Sony Vaio

Tags: keyboard, sony

OK, I know there are bunch of back-lit issues already posted and answered but mine is different so please don't' ignore me. lol.

In windows 7, my keyboard back-lit is always turned on while on AC mode, which I like because I work at night and on AC power most of the time. On battery mode, keyboard lights up when a key is pressed and turns off a few seconds.

Now, I completely removed my Windows and installed Ubuntu 12.10 x64. And I love it. Yes I DO. Though I have issues with it, I've managed to fix some issues but can't figure out this 2 issues.

1. When in AC mode, the back-lit is not "always on" like the way it behaves in Windows before. I'd like to make it always on when I'm in AC mode.
2. I have two built-in card readers, an SD reader and and ProDuo reader. Neither of them works. I have a Realtek RTS5209 card reader --- lspci result.

I'm very new to Ubuntu(Linux). Please help me with this issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: aaah come on.. where's the family?

Comment: I think you should split your issues up - create a question for each one.